# Cannot reach react application via dns hosted on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, react-redux, devops, aws-security-group

I just want to see my development working on an EC2, showing to some friends, and think in deploying it after all of the work is done, but react doesn't cooperate. :/

### **I did everything I always do.**

- Started a ubuntu server on EC2
- applied a group with 3000/tcp opened in my instance
- Installed all dependencies of my app, npm 11.1 and its packages via npm install.
- npm started it
- and...

Nope.. there is no "and"... just my tears over a bunch of attempts without reaching 3000/tcp via public ip and dns..

---

I even tested ping on it.. set ICMP echo request and response rules, tested and it worked, but when I try to reach the application by 3000/tcp port, nothing.

---

> **Does someone have any idea?**

As an image talk more than a thousand words, there it is... [My nighmare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUw2z.png)

> PS: a curl on localhost:3000 inside the ec2 works just fine.. while
>   another curl outside the ec2 returns Connection Refused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the application is bound to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). Update your start property to include `--host 0.0.0.0`

Refer: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/147